A problem with PathFollow3D and camera
When the character follows the path, the camera stays still despite being a child node of the character.
The hierarchy and the PathFollow3D script:
Path
  └── PathFollow3D
        └── Player
              └── Camera



extends PathFollow3D

# Speed of the movement
var speed: float = .5
@export var path: Path3D

var is_moving = false

func _ready():
    # Ensure our node starts at the beginning of the path
    set_progress(0)
    
    # Start the movement
    start_moving()

func _process(delta: float) -> void:    
    if is_moving:
        # Increase the progress to move along the path
        progress += speed * delta
        # Reset the progress if the end of the path is reached
        if progress >= path.get_curve().get_baked_length():
            stop_moving()       
        
func start_moving() -> void:
    is_moving = true
    speed = 0.5

func stop_moving() -> void:
    is_moving = false
    speed = 0


Somehow, I missed that there is a top_level = true property in the _ready() method in my camera script.
This caused the transform property to work incorrectly.
See more in the official documentation.
